# Why does my heap size and thread count increase in this recursive Python code?

Tags: python, memory, python-multithreading

I'm working on finding a memory leak in my application, and narrowed down suspicious activity to this (simplified) code:

```py
import time
import threading

class Work:

    def by_duration(self, seconds: float, block: bool = True) -> None:
        if seconds < 0:
            raise ValueError("seconds >= 0")

        if seconds == 0:
            return

        if block:
            time.sleep(seconds)
        else:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.by_duration, args=(seconds, True))
            t.start()
            return

    def clean_up(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args) -> None:
        self.clean_up()


while True:
    with Work() as p:
        p.by_duration(3, block=False)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Using the tool `memray`, I can watch this code's memory. It both:

1. has an increasing number of threads over time. All threads look "empty" (according to memray). Example:

[image]

2. My heap size increases over time, by about 0.5 kb each iteration.

What's going on? AFAIU, Python should be cleaning up these threads when they finish.

Comment: I can reproduce the memory leak by measuring the process's RSS over time, but I cannot reproduce the constantly increasing number of threads. According to `threading.enumerate()`, Python only has 1 or 2 threads running, no matter how long the program has been running for. Are you sure this isn't an artifact of memray?

Comment: Just thinking outside the box, but could you fix this leak by creating fewer threads? A [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) recycles the same threads over and over to do different tasks.

Comment: Re: an artifact of memray: this is what I thought, too, but I haven't seen any other users reporting this. I also see `threading.enumerate()` return 2.